# bootstrap datepicker not working inside of a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Why does the bootstrap not working inside a javascript but working outside .

Here's my code:

```js
var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     startDate: date,
        autoclose: true,
        format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
        todayHighlight: true,
        orientation: "top auto",
        todayBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: true,  
    });
 var rowCount = 1;

function removeRow(removeNum) {
jQuery('#rowCount'+removeNum).remove();
rowCount --;
rcount();
}

function addMoreRows(frm) {
rowCount ++;
var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><tr><td><input id="datepkr" class="form-control datepicker" style="width:60%; float:left;" name="" type="text"/></td><td><a style="float:left;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red;"></i></a></td></tr></p>';
jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);

  if (rowCount>15){
   $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', true);
  }

}
function rcount(){
 if (rowCount==3){
  jQuery('#x2').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x3').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==4){
  jQuery('#x3').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x4').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==5){
  jQuery('#x4').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x5').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==6){
  jQuery('#x5').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x6').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==7){
  jQuery('#x6').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x7').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==8){
  jQuery('#x7').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x8').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==9){
  jQuery('#x8').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x9').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==10){
  jQuery('#x9').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x10').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==11){
  jQuery('#x10').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x11').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==12){
  jQuery('#x11').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x12').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==13){
  jQuery('#x12').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x13').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==14){
  jQuery('#x13').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x14').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==15){
  jQuery('#x14').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x15').show('slow'); 
  }
  if (rowCount==16){
  jQuery('#x15').hide('slow');
  jQuery('#x16').show('slow'); 
  }
  
  if (rowCount>14){
   $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else{
   $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/blogController.js"></script>

<table> 
 <tr id="rowId">
 <td><input name="" type="text"  value="" class="datepicker"/></td>
 <td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="addMoreRows()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>ADD</button></td>
 </table>
 <div id="addedRows"></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

[Here it is Showing the Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWNWz.png)
  [but in a javascript generated input its not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxzLv.png)

Hope someone will help . Thanks .

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean it's not showing "inside javascript". Where's the inside, where's the outside of JavaScript?

Comment: You need to reinitialize the DatePicker after adding the new row dynamically. I think the answer of @Hardik Patel will work. Good luck.

Comment: First off, your first line is initialized incorrectly.  Specifically, this : `$('datepicker')`.. what is datepicker? A class (add a . before it) or an ID (add a # before it)?

Comment: Sorry guys ,  Ive just updated the code . Run it and click add . And on the input its not showing the datepicker. Now my question is why it is not working (the datepicker) even I use the same class. (form-control datepicker)?. What I mean inside the javascript was the input created on a onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your JS code. Please try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bindDatePicker($('.datepicker'));

  $('button#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var recRow = '<tr><td><input class="form-control datepicker" style="width:60%; float:left;" name="" type="text"/></td></tr>';
    alert(recRow);
        jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
        bindDatePicker($('.datepicker'));
        if (rowCount>15){
            $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', true);
        }
  });
});

function bindDatePicker(element) {
        $(element).datepicker({         
            autoclose: true,
            format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "top auto",
            todayBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,  
        });
}
```

You can check here for demo : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pnpt8wz/2/)